# Скрипт для запуска сервера Django

Tags: django, cmd, bat

хочу заупскать django server с помощью bat файла(если есть еще какой-то вариант, буду тоже благодарен).

```
cd django
start myvenv\Scripts\activate
```

при активации виртуалки открывается новое окно консоли, и не могу понять как писать в него следующий код для запуска сервера.
По сути все что требуется от bat файла это выполнить эти командыЖ

1. перейти в дерективу с виртуальным окружением
2. запустить виртуальное окружение( myvenv\Scripts\activate )
3. перейти к папке с проектом
4. выполнить команду `manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно ходить по папкам, лучше просто вызвать батник перед запуском сервера.

start.bat:

```
CALL .\myvenv\Scripts\activate.bat
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: ввожу `CALL .\myvenv\Scripts\activate.bat` виртуалка не запускается. Папка с виртуалкой на одном уровне с папкой проекта

Comment: разобрался, спсибо!